# How for loop works in python?

Tags: python, list, loops, matrix

I have a lists of lists in variable `lists` something like this:

```
[7, 6, 1, 8, 3]
[1, 7, 2, 4, 2]
[5, 6, 4, 2, 3]
[0, 3, 3, 1, 6]
[3, 5, 2, 14, 3]
[3, 11, 9, 1, 1]
[1, 10, 2, 3, 1]
```

When I write `lists[1]` I get vertically:

```
6
7
6
3
5
11
10
```

but when I loop it:

```
for i in list:
    print(i)
```

I get this horizontally.

```
7
6
1
8
3
etc...
```

So, how it works? How can I modify loop to go and give me all vertically?

Comment: How you say *When I write lists[1] I get vertically:*`6
7
6
3
5
11
10`? its impossible with the `lists` that you have provided!

Comment: And the `for` loop wouldn't give that output either. Please give real examples, and clarify what you're asking: What does "give me all vertically" mean exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would print out the list of lists columns.

```
lists = [[7, 6, 1, 8, 3],
[1, 7, 2, 4, 2],
[5, 6, 4, 2, 3],
[0, 3, 3, 1, 6],
[3, 5, 2, 14, 3],
[3, 11, 9, 1, 1],
[1, 10, 2, 3, 1]]

for i in range(0, len(lists[1])):
    for j in range(0, len(lists)):
        print lists[j][i],
    print "\n"
```

Comment: Yea, so close but I want loop all over the lists and get lists of columns. Not only first column.

Comment: @user3136858 can you be a little more specific? Example output? Ill modify my answer then to be exactly what you want

Answer (score 4):

Short answer:

```
for l in lists:
   print l[1]
```

Comment: Not sure, because index is out of range

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm using a collection iterator in the outer loop rather than a range. Of course, this assumes that all of your lists have at least two elements.

Answer (score 1):

Lists of lists

```
list_of_lists = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
for list in list_of_lists:
    for x in list:
        print x
```

Comment: I was trying that, it gave me rows, but I want columns.